# Is it possible to use 1 DTM rule to send data to multiple integrated tools

Tags: adobe-analytics, web-analytics, mixpanel, web-analytics-tools

This is a scenario for which i need to check the feasibility.

Suppose I have 2 different analytics tools. Let say Adobe Sitecatalyst and Mixpanel. To work with DTM these tools need to be integrated with DTM.

After integration, specific rules will be created. Question is -

Can we create 1 rule, and use it to send data to different tools simultaneously or we need to create different rules.

Comment: You can put multiple tags in a single rule.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes. You can create a single rule and customize the Adobe Analytics section to send whatever you need (using eVars, props, events, etc.). You can also create a third-party JavaScript tag (as part of the same rule) and customize the pixel for Mixpanel.

DTM is really one big JavaScript editor. If you can create JS tag, DTM can execute it.

Hope this helps.
Mark